# Bootstrap 5 bundled with Webpack doesn't work if included in multiple endpoints

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

Here is a quick repo I've created to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/Simpleqode/bootstrap-5-webpack-test.

Basically I have a simple webpack config file with two endpoints one of which imports the whole of Bootstrap, while the second one imports only the Dropdown component to do some magic later. I have Split Chunks plugin in place to move the shared code to a separate file (though the problem persists even if I disable the Split Chunks plugin).

index.js:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

dropdown.js:

```
import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap';
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    dropdown: './src/dropdown.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If you try to run `npm run build` to compile the files, then open `index.html` in your favourite browser, you will notice that the dropdown component doesn't work. Now try to remove `import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap';` from `dropdown.js` or `import 'bootstrap';` from `index.js` and recompile the files - everything will work like a charm. I am new to Webpack and Bootstrap 5 is still an alpha so I am struggling to understand if it's me doing something wrong, Bootstrap or Webpack.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? I'm running into the same issue right now.

Comment: @Quiver, instead of importing bootstrap with `import 'bootstrap'` you need to import all of its modules (e.g. `import { Alert, Button, Carousel, Collapse, Dropdown, Modal, Offcanvas, Popover, ScrollSpy, Tab, Toast, Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';`).